# Reading Array within NSDictionary into UITableViewCell Subviews

Tags: iphone, uitableview, plist, nsdictionary, fast-enumeration

I am attempting to read the plist dictionary below into cells of a UITableView. I want to create a subview for each of the strings contained in the array denoted by the ArrayKey like:

```
Row1: | myString1 |
Row2: | myString2 || myString3 |
```

I've used fast enumeration to read the dictionary, but I can only successfully read the first string in each array:

```
    CGFloat constant = 0;

    for (NSArray key in [dictionary objectForKey:@"ArrayKey"]) {


        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)cell; 
        label.text = (NSString *)key;
        label.frame = CGRectMake(0 + constant, 0, 30, 30);

        constant = 20 + CGRectGetMaxX(label.frame);
        }
```

I'm missing the subview piece. And I'm puzzled why if I add an NSLog of the fast enumeration, the output will show all strings in the array, but I can only display the first (ie myString1 in one row and myString2 in a second row without myString3).

```
<dict>
    <key>TitleKey</key>
    <string>myTitle1</string>
    <key>ArrayKey</key>
    <array>
        <string>myString1</string>
    </array>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>TitleKey</key>
    <string>myTitle2</string>
    <key>ArrayKey</key>
    <array>
        <string>myString2</string>
        <string>myString3</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystifying why this code is working at all. I am sure you are posting only partial code.

1. `UILabel *label = (UILabel *)cell;` will create a pointer to exactly
   the same item `cell` and overwrite whatever is there.
2. If `dictionary` is `nil` then `[dictionary
   objectForKey:@"ArrayKey"]` must cause a crash.
3. `id key` should be `NSString *key` in order to assign it to
   `label.text`.
4. You are not adding the label anywhere as a subview.

You need at least a `[cell.contentView addSubView:label];`.

Comment: You're right it is only partial and I am a super beginner at this. I was hoping for help adding the subview.